Why can we input initial conditions into the CF before finding the PI when using Green's Function?
For any given ODE of the form $x_{p}''(t)+q(t)x_{p}'+r(t)x_{p}(t)=f(t)\quad\forall t>t_{o} \quad \text{subject to } \text{$\begin{cases} \,x(t_{0})=0\\ x'(t_{0})=0 \end{cases}$}$
We may break the solution into two parts: $x(t)=x_c(t)+x_p(t)$
Where $x_c$ is the complementary function and $x_p(t)$ is the particular solution aka the particular integral.
Usually for IVPs we must first find $x_p(t)$ and apply the initial conditions to the general $x(t)$ to find the full solution.
However, when using the Green's Function such that $\displaystyle x_{p}(t)=\int_{t_{0}}^t \text{$\color{green}{G(t\mid\sigma)}$}f(\sigma)\,\, d\sigma$, we always can sub initial conditions into the complementary function $x_c$ and get the correct full solution.
I can see that this is related to the fact that the Green's Function itself does not rely on initial conditions or $f(t)$ but our integral involves $t_0$ and $f(\sigma)$ so that would by my estimation mix up the constants for the full solution with the CF, I am looking for a way to ground my intuition on why this works.

That is interesting to look at a bigger picture of Green function. But I guess you mean that CS (Complete Solution)=CF + PI, where CF denotes complimentary function and PI is particular integral.

Yeah, I meant that when using the Green's Function we can sub the initial conditions into the CF before getting the PI which is usually not the case, usually you should only sub initial conditions after you got both the CF and the PI to then have your full/complete solution.

I am interested in this topic, but I am sure that I have not gained enough knowledge to provide you a complete answer (since I have not understood so much the important theories about the generalized function $\delta$ and Green’s function applications for instance by Kirchhoff and Heaviside).
According to Feynman's Ch25,

a Green's function is a response to an impulse, and the method of
analyzing any force by putting together the response of impulses is
called the Green's function method.

Green's functions are very often used in solving BVPs (Boundary Value Problems), especially extensive in hydrodynamics where by Green's 2nd identity, the solution (therefore Green's function) is determined through boundary conditions of either Dirichlet's or Neumann's type.
The importance is that the Green’s function depends on the differential operator $L$ both through its eigenfunctions and through the boundary conditions which ensures $L$ is self-adjoint (a good example is the Sturm–Liouville operator with  separated boundary conditions), but it does not depend on the forcing function $f(t)$.
Another importance is the linearity, i.e., the superposition principle for solutions. To solve a in-homogeneous equation $Ly=f(t)$. First, we find one particular solution $y_p(t)$ to the homogeneous equation $Ly = 0$ that satisfies the inhomogeneous boundary conditions. This step is usually easy because we’re not looking for the complete solution, just any simple solution. Since the differential operator $L$ is linear, the general solution of $Ly = f$ obeying inhomogeneous boundary conditions is simply
$$
y(t) = y_p(t) + \int_a^bG(t,\xi)f(\xi)d\xi
$$
where the term involving the Green’s function ensures that $Ly$ indeed equals the forcing term $f(t)$, but does not disturb the boundary values.
I hope it will be no misleading and I can refurnish it later.
Referring to MIT18.305 or this post The particular solution using Green's function is the sum of the homogeneous and the particular solution of the undetermined coefficients method?!.
